# How can I combine multiple functions in my address using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have created two different functions that work from the address bar. Now I need to combine them. The first I'm passing on a variable.

```
http://address.com/mimowg.php?g1
```

I need to add this after this. In [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) it's a `+`; what is it in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)?

```
?scd=/net/mfg-scd8/et3mach/status.txt
```

What is the best way to combine these two statements to one working address?

Comment: replace `?` with `&`

Comment: Is this what you want? http://address.com/mimowg.php?g1&scd=/net/mfg-scd8/et3mach/status.txt

Answer (score 3):

Use an ampersand (`&`) to add mulitple GET parameters to your URL.

```
http://address.com/mimowg.php?g1&scd=/net/mfg-scd8/et3mach/status.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, no one doing Python ever expects to do php :/

Comment: Actually, HTTP URLs are the same independent of programming language, it is probably just a matter of how you are generating the final string

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple parameters in a GET request, use `&` to combine them.

```
http://address.com/mimowg.php?g1&?scd=/net/mfg-scd8/et3mach/status.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is a little convoluted.  But it sounds like you are asking to provide multiple GET parameters to the URL.  This is the same whether it's php or python or for anything using http.

You separate multiple parameters using an `&`.  The first parameter follows a `?`

So your url would be something like

```
http://address.com/mimowg.php?g1&scd=/net/mfg-scd8/et3mach/status.txt
```

Although it's better to either name both parameters or leave them both unnamed like:

```
http://address.com/mimowg.php?p1=g1&scd=/net/mfg-scd8/et3mach/status.txt
```